# Can this damage my motorcycle?

Tags: motorcycle, brakes, clutch, kawasaki, ninja

So when I brake, I first hold the clutch to take the power away and then I start braking. The problem is when I try to accelerate again, it takes about 5 seconds for the motorcycle to start moving while giving throttle. Because this is my first bike I don't know if this is normal or not. I'm worried I might be damaging the motorcycle somehow. I do not downshift while doing this. I have a 2018 Ninja 400 ABS. Also I read that the model from this year has problems with the clutch slipping but I don't know what that means. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you say it takes about 5 seconds for the mc to start moving, is that after you've completely let the clutch out (fully engaged)?

Comment: If you're slowing down from over speeding, it's not necessary to pull the clutch, just apply brakes (front and rear). If you're slowing down more than (approximately) 15 mph, you probably need to down shift, pulling in the clutch before shifting. Every motorcycle has its sweet spot of rpm range for overall acceleration. Talk to other bikers to learn about shifting gears.

Comment: this could also be lugging the engine, if you're slowing a lot but not downshifting.

Answer (score 0):

The description in the second sentence is characteristic of a slipping clutch. Your last sentence supports this concept.

In this circumstance, it is good that you are not downshifting during this process, as it will accelerate the damage (increased wear) to the clutch plates. F Dryer is correct that it's not necessary to disengage the clutch if you are simply slowing.

If you've read that this model has problems, consider to follow through to correct the slipping clutch. You should experience movement well before you have completely disengaged the clutch, not five seconds after the action is completed.

Comment: But with the sequential gearbox that most motorbikes have, you *do* have to run down through the gears. If you come to a stop in top gear, it can be quite tricky to move back to neutral. You should always be in the right gear for the road speed regardless of the type of gearbox anyway. And if you correctly match engine speed while downshifting, wear on the clutch plates is minimal. The engine braking on a bike is much greater than on a car, so if you are using the brakes then it is probable that you *are* losing more than 15 mph, which can be done by just closing the throttle.